# Retrieving the row number of a QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

I'm using a QTableView to display some data inside a table. Because no vertical header is given Qt automatically assigns a row-id to a row. The example below displays the following table:

```
id|data
-------
1 | B
2 | A
3 | D
4 | C
```

After sorting the table based on the "data"-column:

```
id|data
-------
2 | A
1 | B
4 | C
3 | D
```

When a user double-clicks an entry, I want to be able to identify the clicked row by its id (i.e. A=2, B=1, C=4, D=3). Unfortunately, the methods used in "onDoubleClicked" only return the "new" row-id (i.e. A=1, B=2, C=3, D=4).

So how do I retrieve the correct row-id, when a user doubleclicks a row?

table.h

```
#ifndef TABLE_H
#define TABLE_H

#include <QTableView>
#include <QModelIndex>
#include <QHeaderView>
#include <QDebug>

class Table : public QTableView {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Table() : QTableView() {
        setSortingEnabled(true);
        connect(this, &Table::doubleClicked, this, &Table::onDoubleClicked);
    }

public slots:
    void onDoubleClicked(QModelIndex index) {
        qDebug() << index.row();
        qDebug() << verticalHeader()->logicalIndex(index.row());
        qDebug() << verticalHeader()->logicalIndexAt(index.row());
        qDebug() << verticalHeader()->visualIndex(index.row());
        qDebug() << verticalHeader()->visualIndexAt(index.row());
    }
};

#endif // TABLE_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QSortFilterProxyModel>

#include "table.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    Table table;
    QStandardItemModel model;

    QList<QStandardItem*> items;
    items.append(new QStandardItem("B"));
    items.append(new QStandardItem("A"));
    items.append(new QStandardItem("D"));
    items.append(new QStandardItem("C"));
    model.appendColumn(items);

    QSortFilterProxyModel proxy;
    proxy.setSourceModel(&model);
    proxy.sort(0, Qt::AscendingOrder);

    table.setModel(&proxy);
    table.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model is not having a new  row(), you forgot that you are passing them via a proxy model. A proxy model holds different rows() and columns() from the original model because it can rearrange or filter fields.

The fix is easy - you just need to map the index from the proxy model to the original one.

```
void onDoubleClicked(QModelIndex index) {
    QSortFilterProxyModel *m = qobject_cast<QSortFilterProxyModel*>(model()); 

    auto sourceIdx =  m->mapToSource(index);
    qDebug() << sourceIdx.row();
    qDebug() << verticalHeader()->logicalIndex(sourceIdx.row());
    qDebug() << verticalHeader()->logicalIndexAt(sourceIdx.row());
    qDebug() << verticalHeader()->visualIndex(sourceIdx.row());
    qDebug() << verticalHeader()->visualIndexAt(sourceIdx.row());
}
```

Comment: Then how to sorting?

Comment: that's unrelated to OP question.

Answer (score -1):

if the value is bind with `A` you can use the `setData` method provided by `QTableWidgetItem`.set the value and get the value back by a specific flag.maybe `Qt::UserRole`

**EDIT:**

base on your code.

`items.append(new QStandardItem("B"));`
then you can get the `QStandardItem` make the `item.setData(1,Qt::UserRole)` while `1` is the value which is bind to `"B"`.Later you can get the bind value from `item.data(Qt::UserRole)`.Note: it would return a variant then you need to transfer it `toInt`

Comment: I'm not sure, if I understand you correctly, could you rephrase your answer maybe? Unfortunately, I don't have access to the individual items as they are added via an QSqlQueryModel.

Comment: You may get the individual items by the `QTableView `.If you can't my method is not available.

Answer (score -1):

These work for me.

```
void DeviceData::doubleClicked(QModelIndex cell)
{
    cell.column();
    cell.row();
}
```

Which you can then feed into your model: `model.at(cell.row())`.
Or you create a `find()` function.